# So geocoder.getFromLocationName returns NULL / USE JSONObject

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, geocoding

Ok so we established that GEOCODER dose not work on some mobiles

So I fond this solution, from a guy called @Filip, which seems legit solution

```js
package com.something.something;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class GetLocationDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

    String result = "";
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    try {
        url = new URL(strings[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(is);

        int data = inputStreamReader.read();
        while(data != -1){
            char curr = (char) data;
            result += curr;
            data = inputStreamReader.read();
        }

        return result;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (result != null) {
        try {

            JSONObject locationObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject locationGeo = locationObject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getJSONObject("lat");




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

And I have to run it from my MapsActivity by this coding this:

```js
String searchString = mSearchText.getText().toString(); 

String link = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + 
searchString + "&key=MY API KEY";

    GetLocationDownloadTask getLocation = new GetLocationDownloadTask();

    getLocation.execute(link);
```

This is all fine, but what I didn't understand is what happens next ? I need those lat lng to process further, how do I get them after EXECUTING(link) ?

Any help is appreciated, it is mind boggling issue. Geocoding needs a backend, and not all devices support.

Answer (score 1):

> This is all fine, but what I didn't understand is what happens next ? I need those lat lng to process further, how do I get them after EXECUTING(link) ?

well, you have result in : `JSONObject locationGeo`, use `getDouble` to parse is as double if that is the correct type.  Actually looking at the end of this long line its latitude, so you need also get longitude. Your further processing should be in onPostExecute (its called on UI thread).

example:

In order to provide `lat` to your activity you should pass a reference to it to your AsyncTask.:

```
public class GetLocationDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, 
String> {
    MapsActivity act;
    GetLocationDownloadTask(MapsActivity act) {
       this.act = act;
    }
```

Then in you `onPostExecute` you use `act` like this:

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

```
if (result != null) {
    try {

        JSONObject locationObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject locationGeo = locationObject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getJSONObject("lat");
        act.passLat(locationGeo.getDouble("Longitude")); // not sure if this is correct
```

then inside your activity execute correct constructor:

```
GetLocationDownloadTask getLocation = new GetLocationDownloadTask(this);
```

I would suggest using here WeakReference to keep activity reference in AsyncTask - but this is more advanced and you are not after that - I suppose.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but still I need to process lat lng e.g. I cannot use JSONObject locationGeo

 .
 .
 .
 .
        getLocation.execute(link);
        
        Toast.makeText(this, locationGeo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: what do you mean by : "I cannot use"?

Comment: I meant how do I call "lat" value in my Activity after executing getLocation.execute(link);

Comment: I still didn't find an answer to my question, can someone help me

Comment: @Naderco-jo I have updated my answer, actually this is the other way around - you execute your Activity-s method from onPostExecute - in this method's parameter you can pass any data.